# How would you loop through array of coordinates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would you loop through array of coordinates using javascript. For example. I have an array in the following format:

```
[[150, 0], [0, 200], [300,200]]
```

for each set of coordinates i'd like to add them to a variable called

```
var pt;
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please do some basic research and make an initial attempt before asking a question about basic control structures such as loops.

Comment: `var pt = [[150, 0], [0, 200], [300,200]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pt;
for(var i=0, n=youArray.length; i<n; i++){
 pt = youArray[i][0]+','+youArray[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with just using a `for` loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var pt = arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pt = [[150, 0], [0, 200], [300,200]].reduce(function(sum, item){  
  return sum+item[0]+item[1];
}, 0);
console.log('pt = '+pt);
```

Not sure if this was the intention, but `reducing` the 2-dimensional array to a single sum.